# Solution of $8x^2+x+1=0\in \mathbb{Q}_2$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

We are asked to determine whether the equation $f(x)=8x^2+ x+ 1$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}_2$. Now, I immediately think to apply Hensel's Lemma, with $\alpha=1$, by which I mean $f(\alpha)\equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, and $f'(\alpha)\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, thus we can find $\alpha'\in \mathbb{Q}_2$ with $f(\alpha')=0\in \mathbb{Q}_2$.

This seemed fine, but in the given solution, the lecturer states that it is necessary to make the transformation $y=8x$, and proceed from there, letting $g=8f$, and then $g(y)=y^2+y+8$, and using $\alpha =1$.

I can only presume that there is a special property of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ that I am missing.

Explicitly, my question is why do we have to make this transformation; is it not sufficient to use my first method?

Comment: If $a$ is a root of $y^2+y+8$, then $a^{-1}$ is a root of $8x^2+x+1$.

Comment: I understand how we can obtain the answer using the transformation, my question was 'why is it necessary in the first place?'

Comment: You are absolutely right, and the lecturer was mistaken. I would use the strong form of Hensel, the one starting from a factorization modulo $p$ and ending with a $\Bbb Z_p$-factorization. Here, your factors modulo $2$ are $x+1$ and $1$, and you use Hensel to get a factor of the same degree as $x+1$, thus a linear factor, thus a root.

Comment: Maybe Hensel doesn't apply when the leading coefficient vanishes mod $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson We have a corollary, which says "If $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ then $\exists \beta \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{\times}$ with $\beta^2=\alpha$, and then in the proof of the corollary, the statement "Hensel Fails". I thought this may be related, but am unsure as to why this would apply here

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the good Hensel absolutely applies when the leading coeff is in the maximal ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s another method, which I like because it’s well-suited to computation. From the relation $\alpha=-1-8\alpha^2$ that’s satisfied by a root of your polynomial, you derive a recursive method of finding $\alpha$, using the Banach Fixed Point Theorem. Start with $a_0=0$, and form $a_i=-1-8a_{i-1}^2$. Gives you your unit root, by taking $\lim_ia_i$.

Comment: A constructive method, very useful thank you.